# Как удалить код g.analytic из html средствами php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть много html-страниц, в которых код гугла аналитики, он пишется по разному, то с пробелами и табуляцией, сносками и прочими символами, в общем по-разному.

Как мне удалить этот код средствами php?

Начнём с того что откроем

```
$file = file_get_contents('index.html');
```

Пытался через регулярки http://regex101.com/, но почему-то не получается правильно составить и подобрать выражение.

Пример кода, который нужно удалить:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-********']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();</script>
```

Помогите решить вопрос. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как-то так:**

```
"/(<script.*>\s*var\s*_gaq\s*=\s*_gaq\s*\|\|\s*\[\].*?<\/script>)/s"
```

http://regex101.com/r/nT3lW4
Условие между тегами, можно немного сократить, на ваше усмотрение.

**Если уж совсем подробно:**

```
$file = file_get_contents("index.html"); //получаем данные из файла

$regxp = "/(<script.*>\s*var\s*_gaq\s*=\s*_gaq\s*\|\|\s*\[\].*?<\/script>)/s";

file_put_contents("index.html",preg_replace($regxp,"",$file)); //заменяем и вставляем новые данные
```

Comment: Странно, но у меня удаляется вся страница начиная с первого <script и заканчивая последним </script> на странице. то есть всё содержимое макета.

Comment: @HA3IK, `$regxp = '/(<script type=\"text\/javascript\">\s.*var.*_gaq.*=.*_gaq.*\|\|.*\[\].*?<\/script>)/ms';`

Так лучше

Comment: @chuikoff, Я только что налепил 3ри скрипта (сверху, снизу, посередине) в куче с HTML и PHP и всё нормально удалилось. Можно увидеть ваш макет?
P.S. И чем ваш шаблон лучше то?)) Как по мне, там много лишнего.

Comment: `[]['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72']['\x63\x6f\x6e\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6f\x72'](self['\x75\x6e\x65\x73\x63\x61\x70\x65'])()`

Скажи пожалуйста, как составить регулярку для вырезки этого кода?
Я пробовал так:
`'/(\[\]\[\'\\x63)(.*)(\(\))/ms'`

Но не сработало

Comment: @chuikoff, Что и откуда должно вырезаться? Только между запятых? С запятыми? Со скобками? Без?  
Создайте вопрос, Я с радостью на него отвечу.

Comment: @HA3IK, http://hashcode.ru/questions/283251/preg_match-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-php

Comment: @HA3IK, Ваше выражение захватит все от первого вхождения `<script` до последнего вхождения `</script>`, если между ними есть  

- var
- _gaq
- =
- _gaq
- ||
- []
в таком порядке. При этом абсолютно не обязательно они должны быть внутри тэгов script:  

    <script>
    </script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || []
    <script>
    </script>
Решение: везде используйте минимальную квантификацию.  

Флаг **m** здесь не нужен. Мало того- он не корректен, так как построчная обработка не требуется. Спасает ситуацию флаг **s** - заставляя захватывать и символы перевода строк как **.\***  
Решение: убрать его.

Comment: И тут подправил )

Comment: @HA3IK, более корректно будет так:  

    /(<script.*?>\s*var.*?_gaq.*?=.*?_gaq.*?\|\|.*?\[\].*?<\/script>

Comment: @ReinRaus, Предновогоднее настроение… у меня рука не поднималась на “жадность” ))  
Cпс, запомню ) **С наступающим!** )